# Iterated integral when $f(x,y)$ is unknown

Tags: integration, iterated-integrals

So we have been given the fact that $ f(3,y-1) = (y-1)(y-3) + f(y,y-1)$
and the assumption is $f_x(x,y)$ is differentiable. I then rearanged to make $f(3,y-1)-f(y,y-1)=(y-1)(y-13). $
Then we need to show that:

$$\int_1^3\int_0^{x-1} f_x(x,y)\,\mathrm dy \,\mathrm dx = -\frac{4}{3}$$

It seems to me the first step is to change the order of the iterated integral to integrate $f_x$ w.r.t. $x$ first. Thus giving $f(x,y)$ and the integral being:

$$\int_0^{x-1}f(3,y)\,\mathrm dy - \int_0^{x-1}f(0,y)\,\mathrm dy $$

but this doesn't really help. 
I then tried to rearrange the limits of the $x$ and $y$ bounds but while closer that didn't seem to help me. The only other process I could think of would be the product of two integrals but I assume that's not possible as it would seem $f_x(x,y)$ isn't single variable. I don't really know what my next step should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{3}\int_{0}^{x-1}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx&=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{y+1}^{3}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}(f(3,y)-f(y+1,y))\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\int_{0}^{2}y(y-2)\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\dfrac{1}{3}y^{3}-y^{2}\bigg|_{y=0}^{y=2}\\
&=-\dfrac{4}{3}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when you switched the order of integration, you switched the limits of integration without changing them. Since there is a variable in the inside integral, you need to sketch the domain of integration and rewrite it.